# How can I break an object apart into pieces of aproximately the same size?

Tags: modeling, objects, cell-fracture

My goal is to create a 3d printable prop for a game (so no need for animation). It will be a tablet (with text and images carved out of it) broken up into half a dozen pieces which the players will need to collect and reassemble.

It should give the impression of having been broken by being dropped while being highly gamable (i.e. it should be 6 pieces of approximately even sizes with the breaks all being across the same two axis so approx 1/6th of the largest face appears on each fragment).

The pieces should look something along the lines of this image, but needn't be so realistic.

[image: photo of what is described]

I'm currently trying to build a proof of concept by creating a plain cuboid and then breaking it apart before I spend time on sculpting a design into it and smoothing out the edges.

I've had a go at using Cell Fracture but I can't see any way to guide where the breaks will be and am getting things like the top right back corner coming off. I'm either missing a lot about how to use it (complete novice here!) or it is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Hello have you tried a Boolean modifier to cut your 6 parts?

Comment: @moonboots - I haven't, but it could be a better way forward. What would be the most sensible approach? I'm pondering duplicating the original object, hacking away 5/6th of it to get the first fragment. Then line the fragment up with the original and subtract it. Then repeat 4 times. Is that the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you want to cut an object into 4 pieces, create the 4 objects that are supposed to cut the object, stick the 4 objects to each others with the *Snap* option for example:

[image]

Duplicate the object and one of the 4 cutting object, give to the object a *Boolean* modifier in *Intersect* mode, apply, then duplicate again the original object and another one of the 4 cutting objects:

[image]

For the example you show me, create a plane, subidivide it, sculpt it a bit, put it where you want the cut to happen:

[image]

Duplicate the objects, use the *Boolean* modifier with the *Difference* mode to get the first half of the object:

[image]

Duplicate the original objects again, select the plane, in *Edit* mode select all and invert its normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > Flip), you get the other half:

[image]

Comment: Given that the finished result is supposed to appear broken (rather than smoothly cut), how best to create the cutting objects so the edges aren't completely flat? (They should be ragged rather than smooth). i.e. this sort of thing: https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1154989714/photo/ancient-greek-text.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=GZtHA8QdBd1XeV2I-iJj1moxtF4XwQsp5EShayUUKd4=

Comment: I've edited my answer, please see if it is what you want

Comment: That looks great. I'll give it a shot in a couple of days when I have a free evening.

Comment: That seems to be doing the job. Next up I'm going to try to put the design in it and then print a piece to see how it goes end to end. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome   ;)  ......